# don't draw line in a line chart for N/A cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

**Edit:** I try to clarify my question, since the replies given so far don't answer it.

If in A1:A5 I have (empty lines describe empty cells):

```
1

2

3
4
```

I get the following chart:

[image]

that is what I need.

However, in A1:A5 I haven't simple values. **I cannot have simple values. I have a repeated formula** resulting from some data processing (so that missing value positions change from time to time), **and hence I cannot have empty cells**.

For example, suppose that in A1 I write `=IF(COUNTIF(C:C,"="&ROW(A1))<10,COUNTIF(C:C,"="&ROW(A1)),NA())` and copy and paste the formula to A2:A5. Then the chart I get is the following one, no matter if I use `=""` or `=NA()` to simulate empty cells:

[image]

Is there any way to not draw the line between "missing" data values?

Comment: I don't have ready access to Excel, but in the chart settings (maybe for the lines or data series), there should be a setting for whether or not to show missing values.  If you can't find that setting for a line chart, try an XY chart (scatter chart).  You also may need to try different combinations of empty, =NA(), and whether it is shown (I forget whether the logic is that showing an NA value leaves a hole, or not showing it skips it).  Line and XY charts may also handle empty cells differently.

Comment: There is a chart named Line with Makers, please go to Insert- Charts and find this kind of chart.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, see how I have plotted the data below.

Right click your chart, and select change chart type.

you will want a `Line Chart With Markers`

[image]

**Note.** The cells that show the "missing" points in the chart have absolutely no data in them. i.e. there isn't a formula that will return a blank, having a blank would result in a zero on the chart, and a continuous line.